# Как бот ТГ может прислать одному из пользователей приглашение в чат?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telegram

Есть бот, который работает через `pyrogram`. Бот принимает что-то вроде заказов на  пиццу. По окончание принятия заказа от клиента, бот должен будет отсылать приглашения всем операторам. "Новый заказ. Кто возьмёт? Вот ссылка в чат" И свободный оператор войдёт в чат по ссылке и уже перетрёт с клиентом чисто по-пацански.

Насколько я знаю, боты сами раньше не могли, инициировать диалог, приглашать к себе в чат на огонёк. Но, что-то ведь изменилось?

Итого, это всё-таки теперь возможно -- чтобы бот отослал сам приглашение нескольким, заранее определённым пользовалям-операторам в чат, к нему? Их user_ID заранее известны.

И как?

Бот сможет отследить, что кто-то из операторов вошёл в чат?

---

Опционально #1 - чтобы ссылка в чат была со случайно-сгенерированным, длинным ID, чтобы её нельзя было переиспользовать. Чтобы генерить новую каждый раз.

Опционально #2 - как только один оператор присоеденился в чат, чтобы ссылка на этот чат становились недействительна автоматически. Или хотя бы чтобы она становилась недействительной по комманде самого бота.